# How can I assign an app to a particular numbered desktop, not display, in macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, desktop, spaces, ventura

I am using Ventura and using an external monitor as my main display and built-in screen as extended display. I have added multiple desktops on both displays. I cannot figure out how I can assign an application to always open in a particular desktop (Desktop 1, Desktop 2, etc.).

I went through [this](https://support.apple.com/sq-al/guide/mac-help/mh14112/13.0/mac/13.0#mchlp03b679a) official guide. There's a section on "Assigning Apps to Spaces". I see four options on ctrl+clicking an app's icon in dock

- None
- All Desktops
- Desktop on Display 1
- Desktop on Display 2

What I am missing is "THIS Desktop". Please tell me how I can achieve this either through pre-build macos features or through some extension/application/script.

Comment: Why downvote this question?  I had the same question and I found the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. The official guide does not seems to be updated. There is no "This Desktop" option. And, "Desktop on Display X" means "Desktop currently active on Display X" which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I think you only get "This Desktop" when you have either one single screen, or have "Displays have separate Spaces" *disabled*, which is what I have here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6eEx.png